# split dataframe into multiple dataframes at certain row string

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(study_unit=c("region", "unit1", "unit2", "unit3", 
                               "region", "unit1", "unit2", "unit3", 
                               "region", "unit1", "unit2", "unit3", 
                               "region", "unit1", "unit2", "unit3"),
                  crop =c("crop_a", runif(3), "crop_b", runif(3), "crop_c", runif(3), "crop_d", runif(3)),
                  crop =c("crop_e", runif(3), "crop_f", runif(3), "crop_g", runif(3), "crop_h", runif(3)))
```

I would like to have it split into four dfs everytime the string "region" appears in the 'study_unit' column, so that I get four dfs like this:

```
df_out <- data.frame(region=c("unit1", "unit2", "unit3"),
                     crop_a =c(runif(3)),
                     crop_b =c(runif(3)))
```

You can see that in the output df, the strings "crop_a" and "crop_b" that are in the same row as the pattern string ('region') in column study_unit, now become the new columns names.

In the rest of the output dfs the columns names should be the rest of the crops (e.g., "crop_c", "crop_d", etc.) along the same row as 'region'

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456550/split-a-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-specific-row-value-in-r) but when I apply it I only get the first split of the starting df.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
split(df1, data.table::rowid(df1$study_unit)) |> 
  lapply(function(x) setNames(x[-1,], x[1,]))
  
$`1`
  region             crop_a            crop_e
2  unit1  0.336660649860278 0.398569785058498
3  unit2 0.0362093998119235 0.573208080604672
4  unit3  0.659518777159974 0.338130323216319

$`2`
  region            crop_b              crop_f
6  unit1 0.872199683217332   0.722637160448357
7  unit2 0.877097567077726 0.00604676897637546
8  unit3 0.557809905614704   0.373338773846626

$`3`
   region            crop_c            crop_g
10  unit1 0.581033685943112 0.330996712902561
11  unit2 0.596002857433632 0.779606226831675
12  unit3 0.257464403286576 0.785003271419555

$`4`
   region             crop_d            crop_h
14  unit1  0.979528269963339 0.578764414880425
15  unit2 0.0909065206069499 0.910437691491097
16  unit3  0.751167086185887 0.802771017653868
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the toy example I showed, this solution works fine. However in the real dataset it seems that it does not always do the split at the correct row (i.e., at the 'region' row). The real data is a bit more complex, but I would expect that there could be a solution based only one column. I have updated the question to show this.

Comment: Hi, @DiegoBrizuela  Kindly check your expected output. it has four numeric rows. maybe it should have three and the first column named _region_ instead of _study_unit_. Check and let me know

Comment: @DiegoBrizuela I updated the proposed solution. Kindly let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

- The answer is in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456550/split-a-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-specific-row-value-in-r) with some modifications, try this

```
df1$a <- cumsum(df1$study_unit == "region")
lst <- split(df1 , df1$a)
lst <- lapply(lst , \(x) x[1:(ncol(df1)-1)])
```

- Output

```
$`1`
  study_unit               crop            crop.1
1     region             crop_a            crop_e
2      unit1   0.21158261061646 0.917511875275522
3      unit2 0.0954579361714423 0.348413035506383
4      unit3  0.676665626699105 0.035933832405135

$`2`
  study_unit               crop            crop.1
5     region             crop_b            crop_f
6      unit1  0.790641463594511 0.416468323208392
7      unit2 0.0656406560447067 0.813903928967193
8      unit3  0.285435270983726 0.308628747938201

$`3`
   study_unit              crop            crop.1
9      region            crop_c            crop_g
10      unit1 0.981320110615343 0.172960462747142
11      unit2 0.653848740737885 0.484351075254381
12      unit3 0.266641739755869 0.468319382052869

$`4`
   study_unit              crop             crop.1
13     region            crop_d             crop_h
14      unit1 0.863889734493569  0.604068135842681
15      unit2 0.760722446488217 0.0434220493771136
16      unit3  0.37153629004024  0.722147275693715
```